# How to read data from div class in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a cart as shown in below example code, I want to create a function in reactjs, which I can call by onclick function, Or how I can call below jquery function from reactjs onclick button function.
I serached a lot and found that findDOMnode can be helpful in this. but did not found such example as per my need. I found it in jquery so, I wrote below code, but not able call this in reactjs onclick function. Thanks.

```
 <body>
   <ul id='cart'>
     <li class="xi">
     <span class='item_pc'>Samosa</span>
     <span class='item_unit'>1</span>
     </li>
   <li class="xi">
     <span class='item_pc'>Jalebi</span>
     <span class='item_unit'>2</span>
   </li>
   <li class="xi">
     <span class='item_pc'>Tea</span>
     <span class='item_unit'>2</span>
   </li>
   <li><a id="xyz" href="#">Submit</a>
   </li>
   <span id='result'></span>
   </ul>
   <script>
     $( "#xyz" ).click(function()
        {
           $( ".xi" ).each(function()
           {
            $item_pc = $( this ).find(".item_pc").text();
            $item_unit = $( this ).find(".item_unit").text();
            $item = $item_pc+"/"+$item_unit;
            $( this ).find(".item_pc").toggleClass( "example" );
            $( this ).find(".item_unit").css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
            $( "#result" ).append("<p>/restaurant/order/"+$item +"</p>" );
          });
       });
      </script>
    </body>
```